# How to make the search form in "Add media" search custom attachment fields?

Tags: search, media

I've added custom fields to image attachments on my site, something like this:

```php
function mysite_attachment_field_to_edit( $form_fields, $post ){
    $form_fields['my_ref'] = array(
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_' . $name, true ),
        'label' => 'Reference',
        'input' => 'text',
        'application' => 'image',
        'exclusions' => array('audio', 'video'),
    ); 
    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'mysite_attachment_field_to_edit', 11, 2 );
```

It works fine and I can even search for images on the site, or in WP's Media Library, using the custom fields by using the [Ivory Search plugin](https://ivorysearch.com).

However, if I want to add an image to a Post, I click "Add media", and search using the field in the "Add media" dialog... but it doesn't seem to search these fields. I get different results compared to searching the Media Library page itself.

Any ideas how to make the "Add media" dialog search custom fields too?

Using WP 6.4.3.